Supabase Oauth redirect not working for localhost
I'm trying to configure my app to redirect to the address: http://localhost:3000/home when the user successfully logs in. I'm using Oauth through Azure to perform authentication. The problem is that the user is not redirected, and remains on /login page. Supabase Azure Oauth callback URL is configured correctly in Azure Panel.
Supabase config:

st_main.js (Pinia Store):
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
export const st_main = defineStore("st_main", () => {
    const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
    async function signInWithAzure() {
        const {data} = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
            provider: "azure",
            options: {
                scopes: "email"
            },
        })
    }
    async function signOut() {
        const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut()
    }
    return {
        supabase,
        signInWithAzure,
        signOut,
    }
})

login.vue (Login page):
<template>
    <q-layout view="hHh lpR fFf">
        <q-page-container>
            <div class="q-pa-md q-gutter-sm">
                <q-btn color="primary" icon="login" label="LogIn with Azure" @click="stMain.signInWithAzure()" />
                <q-btn color="primary" icon="logout" label="LogOut" @click="stMain.signOut()" />
            </div>
        </q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
</template>
<script setup>
    import { st_main } from '@/stores/st_main'
    const stMain = st_main()
</script>

Am I doing something wrong?
What could be happening?
I've already tried applying the redirectTo parameter in the options, but failed.

You need to add the code that is making the redirection.

Supabase should do this through the signInWithOAuth function, using the redirect URL shown in the posted photo, so no additional code should be necessary.

For a PKCE flow, for example in Server-Side Auth, you need an extra step to handle the code exchange. When calling signInWithOAuth, provide a redirectTo URL which points to a callback route. This redirect URL should be added to your redirect allow list.
In the browser, signInWithOAuth automatically redirects to the OAuth provider's authentication endpoint, which then redirects to your endpoint.
async function signInWithAzure() {
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: 'azure',
    options: {
      scopes: 'email',
      redirectTo: `http://localhost:3000/home`,
    },
  })
}

It could be more clear in the documentation, but it is there. You just need to adapt the example.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-azure?queryGroups=environment&environment=client
